# Listing on the App Exchange and Component Exchange

Tags: visualforce-component, appexchange, lightning-apps

I currently have a Lightning Component that I've developed, and will be submitting to the App Exchange for Components. I also have a Visualforce Page which wraps my component (see [this link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.lightning.meta/lightning/components_visualforce.htm)) so that my component can be used anywhere Visualforce is used.

Ultimately I would like to have a listing show up on both the standard [App Exchange for Apps](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/), AND the [App Exchange for Components](http://appexchange.salesforce.com/components).

Do I need 2 separate listings (one for the Visualforce page and one for the Lightning Component) to be listed on the App Exchange and the Component Exchange? Or can I include my Visualforce Page as part of the same package that I'm using to bundle my Lightning Component and somehow indicate that my package should be listed under both directories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let me say that if you haven't already joined the [Partner Community](http://www.salesforce.com/partners) and applied to become an ISV, you really should, as there are Groups in the Partner Community that would be able to easily provide you with a definitive answer to this kind of question. There's also numerous resources to help you prepare yourself for releasing your product to market.

With that having been said, your App will only have one listing. Listings come up under a variety of search terms as just like a web page, they're associated with metadata. On a more practical basis, the Visualforce in your app only serves as a wrapper to allow your component to be used in a standard Visualforce page. From your description, it's not there to provide unique functionality as a stand-alone Visualforce page that functions without the Lightning component.

The Lightning Component is an essential part of your package and the Visualforce page wouldn't be of any use without it. So why would you even want to have 2 listings to maintain? Bottom line, don't expect to have two listings. You don't have two distinct products.